# Training-testing data set for a learning machine using R

Tags: r, machine-learning, time-series, hypothesis-testing

I have been using a learning machine in order to forecast a variable from time-series data. My question comes when I create both data sets with the following script:

```
>library(caret)
>ind=createDataPartition(Data$variable, p=2/3, list = FALSE)    
>train<-Data[ind,]    
>test<-Data[-ind,]
```

These data sets are **randomly** chosen from the whole data set, having 2/3 for training and 1/3 for testing.

Do you consider that this technique is it correct? As my point of view, the predicted data will have a high r^2 because it is a time-series dataset (highly correlated). Do you consider that it would be more beneficial picking the last 1/3 of the data (ordinal technique).

Thanks,
Regards.

Comment: Bootstrapping techniques for time series data are based on blocking, so I'd imagine that cross-validation techniques should be similar.  But someone who deals with time series routinely should weigh in.

Comment: To continue, it seems quite reasonable to use the last third if you're using a single validation set.  But then, why one third?  Why not a quarter?  Should you discard predictions right near the boundary (because of correlation issues)?  If so, how far should such a buffer go for?  What if you want more than one validation set (i.e.: k-fold cross-validaiton).  How big should the blocks be?  And does it matter whether your data-generating process is stationary or not? etc etc.